# How to send data in array to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting a value from an input box in array. I want to post all this into a database with a single insert query so that all relevent data are inserted together in MySQL

Here is my code

```
foreach ($_POST['stop'] as $stopIndex => $stopValue) {
    echo $stopname=$stopValue;
}

foreach ($_POST['timing'] as $timingIndex => $timingValue) {

}

foreach ($_POST['ampm'] as $ampmIndex => $ampmValue) {

}
```

Can anyone help me with correct code where to write insert query

Comment: checking codeigniter user guide would help, see:: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html

Comment: write inside `foreach` loop.

Comment: ya i tried that... but not ble to insert all collected data at once...i want all 3 data to sent in 1 insert query..not seperately

Answer (score 0):

This is example if you use codeigniter's way of fetching data.

Just prepare one array with appropriate keys (relevant to database keys you defined) and import it with the update_batch CI db method.

This is actually method like the one you can use in your model.

```
function save_something() {
    $post_data = $this->input->post();

    foreach ($post_data as $key => $value) {
            $settings[] =  array( 'key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
        }
    }

    $this->db->update_batch('settings',$settings,'key');
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure.

Assumed that you have something like the below.

```
<input type="text" name="variable1['key1']">
<input type="text" name="variable1['key2']">
```

Here `variable1` is an array. When you submit, instead of using "for" OR "foreach" serialize it directly as:

```
$s = serialize($_POST['variable1']);
echo $s;
```

Your `$s` will be something like this:

```
"a:2:{s:6:"'key1'";s:6:"value1";s:5:"'bcd'";s:6:"value2";}"
```

The `$s` can be stored in a single column in the database (type can be text in DB).

While retrieving you can unserialize that column which converts back to array and you can use it easily.

Advantages, less number of records in DB, and in your front end you there is no need to use
looping statements.

UPDATED - TO ADD INTO DATABASE:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key)
{
  $s = serialize($key);
  mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `test`.`abc` (`id` ,`data`) VALUES (NULL , $s)");       
}
```

Serialize value acts as a string, so the resultant will be number of records == number of arrays.

Comment: ya it is working fine but what to pass in my query as a value
$s = serialize($_POST['stop']);
$t= serialize($_POST['timing']);
$a= serialize($_POST['ampm']);
echo $s;echo $t;echo $a;
$data = array(
   'stop_name' => $s  ,
   'timing' => $t ,
   'am_pm' => $a
);

$this->db->insert('t_routes_list', $data);

Comment: no need to put that in array again, send $s, $t, $a into different columns in database that is the advantage of serialize.

Comment: okkk now i under stood wht u want to say :)
but still can u snd me the simple code to insert these 3data(value from 2 input) in diff diff fields table
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='stop["+counter+"]' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='timing["+counter+"]' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><select id='ampm' name='ampm["+counter+"]'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  ";

Comment: Do you want the code to insert into DB ?? As the code i had given was to get the serialize value from form submit !

Comment: i want to get the value from submitt and further insert it into db

Comment: i have edited, please check...serialize variable is nothing but a string....see that your DB column is a "text" to afford a lengthy data

Comment: Please merge your two answers into one.